# Chef: Modify existing resource from another cookbook

Tags: resources, chef-infra

I have two cookbooks: elasticsearch and curator.

Elasticsearch cookbook installs and configure an elasticsearch. The following resource (from elasticsearch cookbook), has to be modified from curator cookbook:

```
elasticsearch_configure 'elasticsearch' do
    configuration ({
        'http.port' => port,
        'cluster.name' => cluster_name,
        'node.name' => node_name,
        'bootstrap.memory_lock' => false,
        'discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes' => 1,

        'xpack.monitoring.enabled' => true,
        'xpack.graph.enabled' => false,
        'xpack.watcher.enabled' => true
    })
end
```

I need to modify it on curator cookbook and add a single line:

```
'path.repo' => (["/backups/s3_currently_dev", "/backups/s3_currently", "/backups/s3_daily", "/backups/s3_weekly", "/backups/s3_monthly"])
```

How I can do that?

Comment: Have you tried using [edit_resource!](https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#id3)?

Comment: I didn’t! Can you provide a small example?

Answer (score 2):

I initially was going to point you to the [`chef-rewind`](https://github.com/thommay/chef-rewind) gem, but that actually points to the [`edit_resource`](https://coderanger.net/rewind/) provider that is now built into Chef. A basic example of this:

```
# cookbook_a/recipes/default.rb
file 'example.txt' do
  content 'this is the initial content'
end
```

.

```
# cookbook_b/recipes/default.rb
edit_resource! :file, 'example.txt' do
  content 'modified content!'
end
```

If both of these are in the Chef `run_list`, the actual content within `example.txt` is that of the edited resource, `modified content!`.

Without fully testing your case, I'm assuming the provider can be utilized the same way, like so:

```
edit_resource! :elasticsearch_configure, 'elasticsearch' do
    configuration ({
        'http.port' => port,
        'cluster.name' => cluster_name,
        'node.name' => node_name,
        'bootstrap.memory_lock' => false,
        'discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes' => 1,

        'xpack.monitoring.enabled' => true,
        'xpack.graph.enabled' => false,
        'xpack.watcher.enabled' => true,

        'path.repo' => ["/backups/s3_currently_dev", "/backups/s3_currently", "/backups/s3_daily", "/backups/s3_weekly", "/backups/s3_monthly"]
    })
end
```